Execute a DDL statement with a variable with Flyway and Mysql
I'm trying to execute a Flyway DDL statement with a variable part.
The code looks like this
SET @s=CONCAT('alter database `', database(), '` CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

So the alter database statement is generated on line 1. It will be different for each environment it is executed in.
Running this migration fails with this error:
Error Code : 1295
Message    : This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet

How can I execute a variable DDL statement like this one with Flyway?

Thus is a limitation of mysql's sql implementation of prepared statement.

Thanks @Shadow. Is there some way to execute a statement like alter database ', database(), ... ? so I need to run an alter database statement using the  database I'm connected to. If I can't use a prepared statement, what are alternative options?

Follow the advice given to the duplicate question - obviously adopting it to your environment.
